# Error- unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta' In Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-datetime

Hi Everyone i have working on Django-framework, I am created on function where i give parameter start_date and end_date, i am trying get previous week start_date and end_date based on start_date but getting
Error - `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'`, please help me out.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

    def report(request):
        start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
        print(start_date) # 2022-06-06
        end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
        print(end_date) # 2022-06-12
        last_week_start_date=start_date - timedelta(days=7)
        last_week_end_date=last_week_start_date + timedelta(days=6)
        d_report = connection.cursor()
        d_report.execute('''select * from table where start_date=%s and end_date=%s''',[start_date,end_date])
```

Answer (score 0):

start_date and end_date are strings. You should convert them to a datetime object. This should be the ISO format so you can use datetime.fromisoformat()

```
start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(start_date)
end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
end_date = datetime.fromisoformat(end_date)
```

Comment: @Georeg Bakaev when i use this method getting Error -Invalid isoformat string: '2022-06-06 '

Comment: There is a space at the end so that won't work. `start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(start_date.strip())` Should work

Comment: than you its working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `start_time` is a `str` type variable. You have to convert it to `datetime` object first, only then you can use timedelta with that.

To convert, you can use this codebase

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: when i use this method getting  Error-  unconverted data remains

Comment: Can you make `print(start_time)` and show me the output?

Comment: print(start_date)= 2022-06-06